# License key generate for java project

Tags: java, security, licensing, license-key

I am creating one Java project.

I want to know how I can create license key for security purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into [TrueLicense](http://truelicense.java.net/)? It's an open source, free software.

I've used it myself to successfully manage licenses on a large scale commercial product. It takes a little work to get it up and running, but it covers all the required bases, and it's hard to beat free.